# Высота listview

Tags: android, java

Привет всем. Делаю вертикальный скроллинг активити. В нем у меня листвью и еще пару кнопок. Но почему-то высота листвью равна одному итему, хотя в нем больше итемов. Если указывать высоту в dp то все нормально, если же `fill_parent` - то высота неправильная.

Comment: У вас ListView случайно не в ScrollView лежит?

Comment: да, в ScrollView. у ListView вообще должен отстутствовать скроллинг.

Answer (score 3):

Открываем документацию по [ScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html), и видим, что чёрным по белому написано:

> You should **never use a ScrollView with a ListView**, because ListView takes care of its own vertical scrolling.

Проще говоря, никогда не помещайте в *ScrollView* то, что имеет собственный вертикальный скроллинг.

Comment: мне вот интересно, а кто-нибудь вообще открывает документацию?

Comment: то есть вообще невозможно ничего придумать? если отключить у ListView скроллинг?

Comment: тогда могу я услышать аналог ListView? который можно также разметить, но он не будет иметь скролла.

Comment: Мне вообще сложно придумать ситуацию, когда могло бы понадобиться засовывать ListView в ScrollView. Не подскажете, зачем?

Comment: Я встрою тебе ListView в ScrollView, чтобы ты мог скроллить, когда ты скроллишь!

Comment: мне не нужен скроллинг в листвью. там максимум будет всего 5 итемов. (первые 5 новостей). я не знаю других компонентов, которые так бы мне подходили как листвью, поэтому использую его. но в то же время, на активити есть и другие компоненты, кнопки, сикбары, текствьюшки и вся страница должна скроллиться.

Comment: Вынесите все эти ваши "другие компоненты, кнопки, сикбары, текствьюшки" в отдельный layout, получите его View через LayoutInflater.inflate, после чего добавьте его к вашему ListView через addHeaderView или addFooterView.

Comment: немного не понял. что это даст? зачем добавлять отдельные компоненты к листвью? может Вы немного не так поняли? эти компоненты находятся не в ListView, а вне его. а в листвью у меня всего 3 TextView. может Вы имели в виду вынести эти 3 TextView?